# getElementsByClassName returns "undefined"

Tags: javascript

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-download')[0];
console.log(element);
```

The class `nav-download` returns undefined for me in console.log. I wanted to know how to handle this.

Comment: Can you include the `HTML` as well

Comment: Please only use English on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you wonder why `document.getElementsByClassName('nav-download')[0]` returns `undefined` - that's because there are no elements with the class `nav-download`. Check spelling mistakes in your HTML if there should be such elements.